# How to load and save view state instances on Ionic 3 to reuse views between pages without instantiating it again?

Tags: angular, ionic3

Let´s say I have an `<ion-list>` with several user `searches` and, on click, it will open a new page using method `openSearch(item)` to display it.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of searches">
    <button ion-item (click)="openSearch(item)">
      <img [src]="item.profilePic" />
      {{item.name}} 
    </button>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

When the user clicks on an item, it will open the page `SearchResultPageDetail` to display the selected search result:

```
openSearch(theSearch: MySearchExample) {
  this.navCtrl.push('SearchResultPageDetail', {
      search: theSearch
  });
}
```

The `SearchResultPageDetail` page receives the parameter `search` and grab its URL. The HTML contains an `iframe`, like this:

```
<ion-content>
  <div> {{ search.name }} </div>
  <iframe class="webPage" id="frame_id" name="samplePage" [src]="search.getUrl()">
  </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

So far so good. I can navigate throw each item and load its url on iframe.

**The problem is when the user go back and open the same item again. It loads the iframe again**. I would like to keep it in a cache or in a variable and, if URL was loaded before, it loads from cache (or variable) instead of loading from web again. Just for information, those iframes takes about 10 to 15 seconds to load, even with fast internet.

I already studied about `templateRef` and `View Container`. I don’t think I’m on the right way, I couldn’t find any answer.

I also thought about saving the iframe `DOM` on some Main page (available to all Ionic pages) but I don’t know if it is possible, I don’t know if it will work neither. And I don’t know how to save and load it.

The final idea is the user being able to search on several pages with only one query. Moreover, that the user can navigate throw all the App functionality and return back to search pages quickly, without loading the iframes again if already loaded.

I appreciate any help! Thank you…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the content of IFrame and save it in localstorage / Ionic storage based on ur needs.

```
declare const document: any;
var value = document.getElementById('frame_id').contents().find("body").html(); 
localStorage.setItem("frame_id", value);
```